# How to calculate the difference between the Date created of two records

Tags: microsoft-access, sql, microsoft-access-2010

I have an Access table. The table has two main fields: `OperatorId` and `DTCreated`.

I am trying to devise a way to calculate the time between two records based on the `DTCreated` field.

Can anyone assist with this?

[image]

Comment: Probably the same as excel subtract for the difference and format as necessary.

Comment: Need to show in field as part if the query please elaborate

Comment: Try it and see what you get - I'm on a smartphone at the mo...

Comment: You could take both dates into vba and do the calc there , returning the value.

Comment: I didn't think it needed vba surely ? I could do it with vba the end game is to use the top 10 records between the transactions in a downtime report

Comment: See if you can use [DateDiff() function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateDiff-Function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f)... I know SQL but not so much Access but have played with it some here and there from time to time so this may be a good starting point for you at least.

Answer (score 0):

Update On the Query

So the below SQL returns but it takes so long to run (10 mins) and as soon as access shows the data it crashes? can anyone help?

`SELECT TestDataset.ID, TestDataset.OperatorID, TestDataset.DTCreated,(
SELECT TOP 1 t2.DtCreated 
FROM TestDataSet
WHERE t2.OperatorID = TestDataset.OperatorID AND t2.DtCreated < TestDataset.DtCreated
ORDER BY t2.DtCreated,t2.ID) as PreviousTransaction ,Minute([DtCreated]-[PreviousTransaction]) AS Minutes
FROM TestDataset
ORDER BY TestDataset.OperatorID, TestDataset.DTCreated;`